# Odoo - Sales Order Graph View grouped by parent_id

Tags: odoo

Can you please help me to modify my Sales Order Graph View, grouping by *parent_id* for clients who have *parent_id*?

For clients that does not have *parent_id,* the graph should group by *partner_id.*

Comment: Can you show what you have tried thus far?  You'll get more help by showing your coding attempts and research effort.

Comment: When I edit the graph view of the "Sales/Sales Orders", the following code can be edited: 
<?xml version="1.0"?><graph string="Sales Orders" type="bar">
                    <field name="partner_id"/>
                    <field name="amount_total" operator="+"/>
                </graph>
I have one sales order to client "CompanyX" and another sales order to the client "CompanyX, Peter Smith". I would like to have a graph summing the amounts of "CompanyX" and "CompanyX, Peter" - since they are the same company.